# Google Sheets query how to make MATCHING skip (not match with) blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am running a query in Google Sheets to analyze a bank account statement's transaction text (column D) against predefined categories (found in range `$T14:$BG14` for this particular row).

My problem is that every once in a while the transaction text is blank, and within my range of predefined texts there will also be blanks for certain categories, which produces a false match. As you can see from the screenshot below, each category can be set to match against any number of transaction texts.

Is there a way to make this line

```
D matches '" & JOIN("|";$T14:$BG14) &"'
```

only match if the value is not blank (or null or whatever Google Sheets will identify an empty cell as)?

---

Here is the entiry query, and some sample data.

```
QUERY(
    'Kontoutdrag länsförsäkringar'!$A$2:$F$999176;
    "SELECT sum(F) WHERE 
        B >= date'" & TEXT(DATEVALUE(C$4);"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND
        B <= date '"& TEXT(DATEVALUE(C$5);"yyyy-mm-dd") &"' AND
        D matches '" & JOIN("|";$T14:$BG14) &"'
        label sum(F)'' ";
    )
```

Cells U17 and V17 in this screenshot will for example create a match for every line on my bank account statement that lacks a transaction text.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add this: `AND D != ''`

So your whole line would go:

```
D matches '" & JOIN("|";$T14:$BG14) &"' AND D != ''
```

As I was describing the problem the answer came to me, and I realize it's rather simple, but since I spent this time writing up the question I might as well post it rather than just deleting everything.