# Using query function with (matches) empty cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

```
=query(A1:S10,"select C,D,E,F,H,K,P,R,S WHERE Q='USA' AND R matches 'Florida|NY|'''
```

I would like to add (or empty cell) to the 'Florida|NY'
That is to say I would like to select rows with the Q= 'USA' and R matches either 'Florida','NY' or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `OR R is null` to your `SELECT` statement.

Related

- [Google Sheets Query Get Row When Any of These Cells are Not Empty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72686/88163)
- [Google Sheets query how to make MATCHING skip (not match with) blank cells?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/141785/88163)